# I earned +100 reputation 'because we trust you on other sites of the network' on all stackexchange sites that i am on other than philosophy

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

Is there a reason for this?

Its pretty annoying not being able to comment.

edit: I don't have it in code golf either

Answer (score 3):

Sorry 'bout that. You should have the bonus on all your sites now.

Comment: Thank you. what was the problem anyway?

Comment: @puser The short version is that when we detect that an account deserves this bonus, we tell every site it has a profile on to grant that bonus. Sometimes that fails for a variety of reasons - communication between machines, database issues, star alignment, etc.

Comment: Star alignment causes a lot of frustration among devs.